Misbehaving JSTL forEach
Problem definition: JSTL tags work in my JSP with the exception of forEach. Behavior is that it ignores request objects. It works for objects created on the page, but for objects coming in from request it fails. My ignorant view is that it appears to not be detecting the request object. I can save you a lot of questions by confirming that a scriplet and some Java code confirms that the ArrayList arrives to the JSP, and I have even processed it item for item and proven that the list was in fine shape.  Rest assured, the list DOES make it to the JSP and I am currently relying on scriplet to make the app work.
That being said, here is my (questionable?) configuration:

Tomcat 10.1.25

WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-3.0.1.jar, jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-3.0.0.jar

In JSP header: <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="jakarta.tags.core"%>

The offending forEach loop:
 <c:forEach items="${prodList}" var="prods">
   <c:out value="Inside forEach ..."/>
   <c:out value="${prods.prodID}"/>
   <c:out value="${prods.prodName}"/>
</c:forEach>


Servlet: request.setAttribute("prods", prodList);

Project Deployment Assembly: /src/main/webapp = /

Project buildpath has the two JSTL jars

Strangely, when I type <c:forEach to create the tag it immediately barfs and says there is a problem with, and I quote, "org.apache.taglibs.standard.tei.ForEachTEI, which is a class that I have doubts about.  It is a member of the aforementioned jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-3.0.0.jar (org/apache/taglibs/standard/tei/ForEachTEI.class).  But whence the jakarta namespace? Why apache?


This stuff makes me want to tear the rest of my hair out.
Bottom line is that scriptlet works and the tag does not. The tag appears to simply ignore any request objects. Yes, other tags work. It's about forEach.

Are you certain all the jars are the correct versions? The Jakarta namespace was introduced when JSF was moved outside of Oracle.

The two jars were recommended for Tomcat 10.1.x in another post by somebody named Balus or similar name.  They are the 3.0.0 and 3.0.1 jars but I don't know how to rectify the answer to your question in any more specificity.

The API library you referenced doesn't contain an implementation of the JSTL tag library which you probably didn't defined in the JSP. Anyway, without a code is impossible to suggest. You should refer to this answer to choose and usage of JSTL with  Apache Tomcat.

@Mexicano_con_ingles BalusC usually knows what he is talking about, so you may not be doing exactly what he thinks you are doing.  That said, you may want to do a prototype in an IDE supporting JSF bringing in its own runtime stack.  In the old days that was NetBeans.

Thanks for your assistance, guys, will work on suggestions.

No change after running on Tomcat 10.1.26. Double checked the ForEachTEI.class in the 3.0.1.jar against the one at Glassfish and it is the same size and create date.

If anybody is still interested I tried replacing my WEB-INF/lib jars with the ones from Glassfish.  It made things not better is one way to say it. Immediately the editor started showing that no tags were recognized as tags.  So, back to the two jars recommeded by BalusC and I found the following: TagExtraInfo.class exists in the Glassfish jakarta.servlet.jsp-api.jar, but it does not exist in either of my BalusC jars.  Then I found that my impl jar does have ForEachTEI.class but it's not in the api jar. Don't know what all this means. I may try Netbeans later today.

Maybe the missing TagExtraInfo.class is not a deal-killer.  To wit:                                public abstract class TagExtraInfo  extends Object
Optional class provided by the tag library author to describe additional translation-time information not described in the TLD. The TagExtraInfo class is mentioned in the Tag Library Descriptor file (TLD).
This class can be used:
to indicate that the tag defines scripting variables
to perform translation-time validation of the tag attributes.


I feel like an idiot but I had REVERSED the items and var!  There was nothing wrong with the JSTL libs, just my brain was wired wrong when staring at the problem of the items being EMPTY. Null items object means nothing happens, as if the forEach is braindead.  It wasn't.  It was doing what I asked it to do!
